# multi-class classification problem with low precision values in classifications 4 and 5

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision, random-forest, multilabel-classification

I have classification dataset. In the sata dataset there are 5 classifications, namely 1,2,3,4 and 5. I have modeled machine learning (Random Forest Classifier) to create a classification model. However, in the classifocation report, the precision value of classification 4 and classification 5 is very small and results in an exchange of values or wrong predictions in classification 4 and classification 5. What is the solution?

i have done hyperparameter tuning and have the same results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.